# Github insert history into downloaded file

Tags: git, github

years ago I used a change management system ( maybe PVCS ) where you could add code to the files so that the metadata ( commit date, comment ) showed up in the file you were downloading. Does GitHub have anything like this ?

Comment: GitHub doesn't. Git [does](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) but [it is not recommended](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Does_Git_have_keyword_expansion.3F).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Any "keyword expansion" is a feature of **tool**, while GitHub is just **service on top of tool** (Git)
2. As noted by @phd, you can have (beware of headache) keyword expansion in Git with gitattibutes, but more native and natural way is using own smudge + clean filters, not hardcoded subset of keywords

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusing in naming. I had used command line vcs before, as well as one with a GUI. I finally found a video that explained the relationship between Git, github and the github desktop. I was wondering why I had to commit AND push.  Sad about the expansion, it would remove the "lets put that change log in the file" work.

Comment: @GoGoPuffs - technically speaking, any (?) common keyword in any single file of multi-file project isn't changelog per se (while you haven't ``git log` as keyword), but "checkmark", and, because you deploy **snapshot**, you have to know really only one thing: to which changeset this deploy belongs in order to maintain it in process. If you want changelog - build it into some file and deploy

Comment: Sadly, the team isn't there yet. There are still thinking in terms of "what has changed with this file" rather than changesets. We are working in SQL , that doesn't really lend itself to code, compile, build, deploy. There are no common files, no interdependencies, no libraries. Currently, there is not even a dev, QA, production. People just code locally to do their work. Working on installing "better practices" but baby steps. Thanks.

Comment: @GoGoPuffs - well, still can't grok: even for SQ-file every dev can have repo, can `git log` in it. Why, for which reason, it has to be duplicated outside VCS? Please, describe the process slightly more deeply in your question - comments are too short for this

Comment: It is an adoption issue.  The current process is change log in file, no SCC. So I am trying to introduce SCC and also maintain what they have now ( baby steps )  With git log, they have to do an extra step.  I actually had  a manager balk at tagging files  for release because that meant their group had to do an extra step. We are too small to have a dedicated release managers ( but I suspect the job will become mine across the divisions because no one wants the extra work ) . CMM of 0 .

Comment: To add:  this is the current development process. Devs meet with consumers, Mary wants a column added to a view. Developer changes said view, adds to changelog and done. There is no PM group, no cross division business decisions.  It is all one off changes.